# Passing multiple parameters to an MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched and found several questions similar to mine, but the answers are too specific to the OP's situation to help.

On my Main view, I have a table of items and action links for each of those items:

```
Item Name   Actions
Item #1     Foo | Bar
Item #2     Foo | Bar
```

The Main view displays this table with the following code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Foo", "Index", "Test", item, null) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Bar", "Index", "Test", item , null)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

As you can see, each item in the Main view's table links to the Test controller/view.

The Test controller's Index action is defined as:

```
    public ActionResult Index(Item item)
    {
        return View(item);
    }
```

The Test view is then defined to accept the Item model:

```
@model Models.Item
```

This all works and the Test view displays the Item object's data.

However, I now need Foo and Bar to display the Test controller/view in two distinct ways, or modes.

Something like:

```
?mode=foo&item=Item
?mode=bar&item=Item
```

How do I pass both the Item object and a mode to my Test controller so that the Test view will behave appropriately based on the mode?

Answer (score 1):

Add the mode to the route values.  You'll have to expand `Item`'s properties

```
@Html.ActionLink("Foor", "Index", "Test", new { mode = "foo", propA = item.PropA }, null)
```